Corrupted display from QPixmap.fromImage
When running the following code, I find that the displayed image is corrupt - consistently on Windows, intermittently on macOS.
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout

app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()
window.resize(200, 200)

picture_view = QLabel('Image View')

def wrap():
    qimage = QImage(b"\x00\x00\xff\xff"*200*200, 200, 200, QImage.Format.Format_RGB32)
    return QPixmap.fromImage(qimage)
pixmap = wrap()
picture_view.setPixmap(pixmap)

layout = QVBoxLayout(window)
layout.addWidget(picture_view)

window.show()
app.exec()


If I remove the wrap() function, so that the middle portion is just
qimage = QImage(b"\x00\x00\xff\xff"*200*200, 200, 200, QImage.Format.Format_RGB32)
pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(qimage)
picture_view.setPixmap(pixmap)

the problem goes away.

Does anyone know if this is considered to be a bug in PyQt6, or is my code violating some established principle?
Is there any way to keep the structure where qimage exists only in wrap() without this corruption? Some way of instructing the QPixmap instance to load the data into itself?
Or is the official advice that the user needs to keep a copy of the QImage around, even after passing it into a QPixmap?
Thanks for your time.

This is caused by Qt's implicit data sharing. The QImage will be garbage-collected when wrap returns, which may mean some of the shared data is no longer accesible. To avoid these problems, call pixmap.detach() to enforce a copy-on-write.

Thanks very much for your response! Exactly what I was looking for.
